# How to solve Mysql to mysql as I have some problems

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, web-crawler

Th problem: it says

> Deprecated: mysql_pconnect(): The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/...

I think I have change mysql to mysql but how?

```
<?php

    $database="sphider_db";
    $mysql_user = "root";
    $mysql_password = ""; 
    $mysql_host = "localhost";
    $mysql_table_prefix = "";



    $success = mysql_pconnect ($mysql_host, $mysql_user, $mysql_password);
    if (!$success)
        die ("<b>Cannot connect to database, check if username, password and host are correct.</b>");
    $success = mysql_select_db ($database);
    if (!$success) {
        print "<b>Cannot choose database, check if database name is correct.";
        die();
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> > MySQL extension was deprecated in PHP 5.5.0, and it was removed in PHP 7.0.0. Instead, the [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO_MySQL](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) extension should be used.

Use [`MySQLi-connect`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php) insted of `MySQL_connect`
as well as instead of `mysql_select_db` use [`mysqli_select_db`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.select-db.php)

---

**EDIT 01**

in `mysqli_connect` you can select database too

```
$link = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1", "my_user", "my_password", "my_db");
```

Comment: "When I change  mysql_connect to mysql_connect then I face this problem: Cannot choose database, check if database name is correct."

Comment: @Pinalla check my answer. i have mention all

Comment: Should I change all the mysql to mysqli...

Comment: @Pinalla needs to go read the tutorials for both API's, then make a selection and learn to code for that selection. It isn't as simple as trading one function name for another.

Comment: @Pinalla [check this link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php#refsect1-function.mysqli-connect-examples). you can easily identify this

Comment: @Pinalla happy to help :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to [stop using `mysql_*` functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php). [These extensions](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.removed-exts-sapis.php) have been removed in PHP 7. Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and consider using PDO, [it's really pretty easy](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

Comment: "Thank you very much, I need PDO..."